# Is there a simple way to extend the Coral UI js object to add custom elements?

Tags: javascript, aem

In our current project we're using AEM 6 and want to be able to create custom Coral UI controls (and use them with Granite UI). Creating the JSP files is straightforward and locating them in apps so they're available is also simple. However adding the associated JavaScript functionality is more complicated - is there a prefered way to extend the Coral UI javascript instances as the code all appears to be in closures and not extensible?

Answer (score 0):

The CUI namespace is available under window so you can use it to create your own component. Are interesting in modifying an existing component, or creating a new component that extends CUI.Widget?